# jQuery function is not working in TYPO3 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, typo3, typo3-extensions

I am using TYPO3 version 10.2.2. I add the following lines of code in my JavaScript file it is not working. It working fine in TYPO3 8 and 9.

Code reference link: https://codepen.io/iiCe89/pen/LkKOrY/

```js
$.contactButtons = function(options) { 
  alert('here');
  var defaults = {
    effect: '', // slide-on-scroll
    buttons: {
      'facebook': {
        class: 'facebook',
        use: false,
        icon: 'facebook',
        link: '',
        title: 'Follow on Facebook'
      },
      'google': {
        class: 'gplus',
        use: false,
        icon: 'google-plus',
        link: '',
        title: 'Visit on Google Plus'
      },
    }
  };
};
```

Alert is not working inside the function.

Thank you

Comment: Your JavaScript Code has nothing to do with TYPO3 at all. Did you check in the Browser if your JavaScript file was included correctly?

Comment: Did you check your browsers console? Maybe your JavaScript is loaded before jQuery, you could see that in the browser console.